# Playing mp3 file hosted on public google drive folder

Tags: android, media-player, google-drive-android-api

Is there a way to play mp3 files hosted on public google drive folder on Android Media Player as a stream?
I was working on a simple Music app and for the initial version, I wanted to host files on google Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Media Player will accept any direct link of an audio/video file as an input.

I believe Google has discontinued the file hosting service year ago.  [Refer here](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html)